# "Any correction" or "any corrections": Are they interchangeble?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I know that the noun "correction" is both countable, meaning a change that makes something more accurate than it was before, and uncountable, meaning the act or process of correcting something. When I want to say, "Any correction is appreciated," should I say "any corrections', or are they both correct? Here, I'm referring to my correcting a friend's essay.

Comment: Personally, I differentiate by likelihood of appearing of more than one. If given text is brief, believed to be correct, and I find "0 or 1" to be the likely number of corrections, I'll ask for "any correction". If there's a likelihood for more than one, I'll ask for "any corrections".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**, both are accepted.

The difference is that when saying *any correction is appreciated*, you can expand it to *any **act of** correction is appreciated*.

*Any corrections are appreciated*, on the other hand, can expand to *any **number of corrections** is appreciated*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are correct.

That's because the word *any* can refer to one or more things i.e. singular and plural.

> [any](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=any) - ***One, some, every or all*** without specification.

This said, any *correction* would mean one time/single correction and making it plural means more than one *corrections.*

They are interchangeable unless you are peculiar about the *number* of correction/s.

Comment: What do you mean by "single correction"?

Comment: @Vic 'There are a boy' has one/single correction - *is*; 'Theer are a boy' has more than one correction *There* and *are*.

Comment: So you mean to say that if I say,"Make any neccessary correction", there would only be one correction to a mistake,in a passage, for example or are we talking about the "act" of correcting?

Comment: @Vic I personally don't go with *act* there. Though no downvote. How I look your question heading as 'any suggestion' or 'any suggestions'. And hence, it's clear to me.